# what does if(!(x%3)) mean?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to solve a hw problem in which I need to write down what the program will output. I am stuck however, on the syntax "if ( !(i%3)). What does that really mean? Does it mean that the program is checking for any i that is divisible by three? aka, is the if statement only runs if i is divisible by three?

```
int main () {
for (int i=0; i<10; (i<3?i++;i+=2)) {
    if (!(i%3)) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (i%7 ==0) {
        break;
    }
    cout << i<< endl;
}
```

Comment: *"Does it mean that the program is checking for any i that is divisible by three?"* That is correct.

Comment: yes... your code skips all the `i`s which are divisible by `3` and `7` and process the rest

Answer (score 6):

> Does it mean that the program is checking for any i that is divisible by three? aka, is the if statement only runs if i is divisible by three?

Correct. The longer version of that check would be

```
if (i % 3 == 0)
    continue;
```

The most common use case for such branching is probably [FizzBuzz](https://hackernoon.com/why-im-still-using-fizz-buzz-to-hire-software-developers-7e31a89a4bbf).

Answer (score 2):

İt means if `i` is not(!) divisible by 3 continue.
For example if `i` is 3,6,9 it won't continue otherwise it will continue.

Answer (score 1):

`if (x)` where `x` is `int` implicitly compared with zero. I.e. `if (x)` equals to `if (x != 0)`. `!` is negation. So `if (!x)` equals to `if (x == 0)`. And the last step is `if (!(i%3))` equals to `if ((i%3) == 0)` what is the same with check, that `i` deivisible by 3

Answer (score 1):

The **if()** statement is false only if the result inside the parentheses  is 0 (false). Take a look at your program:

**i%3** may return 0 (false), 1 (true), or 2 (true)

The negation operator **!** changes the result of the operation **(i%3)**. So, if the **i** is divisible with 3 the statement will return **0 (false)**. Being negate, ! it will result in **True**. Otherwise the result of **(i%3)** will be **true** and with the operator **!** the result of the hole statement will be **false**. Basically this code is checking if the value of i is divisible with 3.

Other options will be:

```
if (0==i%3)
{
/*code*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified as below

```
int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<10;) 
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (i % 7 == 0) {
            break;
        }

        cout << i << endl;

        i = i<3 ? i+1 : i+2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write a integer variable like `i` as a condition, what happens is that if `i==0` then the result of the condition is `false`, otherwise it would be `true`.

Let's check it out in your program, `if(!(x%3))`, let's name `condition= !(x%3)`, when this condition is `true`? when `x%3 == 0`, note that the negation operator `!` is behind `x%3`, so in this case the `condition` would be equal to `true`, more formally the condition is equal to :

`if(x%3==0)`

these kinds of conditions are common, check this example out :

```
int t = 10;
while(t--){
    cout<<t<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The above condition i.e `if(!(i%3))` will true when " i is not disvisable by 3"
Hope this helps.

Comment: if i is not divisable by 3 the result will be non-zero and if will fail

Comment: Exactly! Then it will go for next statement.

Answer (score -1):

In java and other languages there is a special type to represent booleans and evaluate expressions; in c and its variants there is no such thing, instead an expression is considered "true" if -taken as a integer number- is equal to 0; false for every other value. (*Fun fact: this is why you usually end the code by `return 0`*)

So `if(x%3)` in c is equivalent to `if(x%3==0)` in other languages. That said, `if(x%3)` execute the if body when the remainder of x/3 is 0, that is when x is a multiple of 3. 
In your code you have the `!` before, that -as you may know- "inverts" the expression. That means that `if(!(x%3))` can be read as "*If the remainder of the integer division of x by 3 is not 0*", or alternatively: "*If x is not a multiple of 3*".

So, basically, you saw it right.

Hope I helped!